# Which MCU ADC configuration works best for bipolar input measurement

Tags: adc, negative-voltage

The jumper pads can be set to configure the input pins connected to an MCU. Which configuration would work best to enable reading negative voltages?

[image]

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking ... there is only one option with a negative voltage in the table ... there is no `best` in a group of one

Comment: Dustin LaRoche - Hi, (a) As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as site rules here differ from typical forums. (b) One of those site rules requires that material copied or adapted from elsewhere and put onto Stack Exchange, be correctly [referenced](/help/referencing). Where did that image come from? It shows a URL, but there isn't a clickable link to the original webpage, and I didn't find that *exact* image. So to comply with the SE site rule, please [edit] your question & add the original webpage link & its title. If you adapted that image using multiple webpages, list them all.

Answer (score 1):

#### Only one configuration supporting negative voltages

> Which configuration would work best to enable reading negative voltages?

Based upon a search the picture in the question is from the  [6 Ch. 12 Bits Raspberry Pi ADC HAT with ESP32-C3](https://seenov.com/rpi-adc-hat/) product.

In the above referenced web page it says:

> Input Pad Configuration : Each ADC has a set of configuration pads that be used to attenuate the input signal and even offset it to +1.25 Volts, making it possible to read ±12V or 0-24V signals. On channel 0, in the picture, **JP 7 is used to enable or disable bipolar measurements**, while JP1 and JP4 are used to set the division ratio. Measurements of 0-750mV, 1050mV, 1300mV or 250mV are possible with the built-in attenuation while bypassing the resistor divider.

Which means there is only one option to enable negative voltages.

And [ESP32C3 6 channel ADC for the Raspberry Pi Specifications](https://seenov.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/ESP32C3-ADC-hat-specifications.pdf) also only shows one option for negative voltages in the features:

> • 5 ADC inputs configurable for 0-0.750 to 2.5V, **±12V** or +24V.

So, to answer the question there is only one configuration for reading negative voltages.

#### Not sure of the ADC accuracy

This product seems to only use Wireless UDP communications with the Raspberry Pi, since the specifications contain:

> • Wireless UDP communications with Raspberry Pi.
>
> • No use of any Raspberry Pi IOs.

And [Raspberry Pi ADC ESP32 Hat Incredibly Measures ±12v With Great Accuracy](https://seenov.com/raspberry-pi-adc-esp32-hat-incredibly-measures-%C2%B112v-with-great-accuracy/) contains:

> With a Wi-Fi transmitter generating rf signals, it is to be expected that some noise **will pollute the ADC inputs**. For this reason, we recommend averaging the results over as many samples as possible.

While the question doesn't mention any accuracy requirements for using the ADC, from the manufacturers specification the achievable accuracy isn't clear.